# Error with robocopy in batch file

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have this batch file to copy all file from one directory to another directory. The source and destination directory are write in a text file. So I have this:

BATCH FILE

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2,3" %%j in (C:\temp\copy_list_test.txt) do ROBOCOPY.EXE %%j %%j\..\BACKUP *.* /R:2 /W:5 /log+:%%j\..\LOGS\GOLD2MES.log & ROBOCOPY.EXE %%j %%k *.* /R:2 /W:5 /MOV /log+:%%j\..\LOGS\GOLD2MES.log
```

and this is a copy_list_test.txt file

```
TC C2 #001 from instrument to C:\temp\GOLDS\IMPORT:C:\temp\MESSE\IMPORT
```

So when I try to run the script he create a new folder on "C:\Users\mcastrio\Desktop\C\" and not put file in C:\temp\MESSERVER

Where is my error?

Can we help me? Best reguards

Comment: Have you tried debugging, perhaps by adding an echo statement instead of running robocopy, to see what you would be executing?

Comment: This is a text into log file:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Nov 20 11:37:06 2014

   Source : C:\temp\GOLDSERVER\IMPORT\
     Dest : C:\Users\mcastrio\Desktop\C\

    Files : *.*
     
  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:2 /W:5 
If you see the dest source is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using colons as delimiters in the input file, the tokenizer sees

```
TC C2 #001 from instrument to C:\temp\GOLDS\IMPORT:C:\temp\MESSE\IMPORT
^.............................. ^................. ^ ^.................
1                               2                  3 4
```

That is,

```
%%j = \temp\GOLDS\IMPORT
%%k = C
```

You can change your `tokens` clause to `tokens=2,*` to obtain

```
TC C2 #001 from instrument to C:\temp\GOLDS\IMPORT:C:\temp\MESSE\IMPORT
^.............................. ^................. ^.................. 
1                               2                  3
```

But remember the drive reference in `%%j` has been lost.